# Golang Gin Binding Request body XML to Slice

Tags: go, go-gin

I am having an issue with the default binding in Gin. I have an incoming request where the body is multiple Entity objects like so:

```
<Entity>
  <Name>Name One here</Name>
  ...
</Entity>
<Entity>
  <Name>Name Two here</Name>
  ...
</Entity>
```

My goal is to map it to a corresponding slice. So the struct for the desired object is like so:

```
type Entity struct {
  XMLName xml.Name `bson:"-" json:"-" xml:"Entity"`
  Name   string    `bson:"name,omitempty" json:",omitempty" xml:",omitempty"`
  ...
}
```

The problem I'm experiencing is that **only one** of the supplied objects is ever mapped into the slice, regardless of how many are passed in the request body. Note that the JSON version of the request parses correctly.

```
[
 {
   Name: "Name One",
   ...
 },
 {
   Name: "Name Two",
   ...
 }
]
```

I have a struct to model request structure

```
type ApplicationRequest struct {
  XMLName      xml.Name `bson:"-" xml:"Entities"`
  Entities     []Entity `binding:"required" xml:"Entity"`
  ParameterOne bool
  ...
}
```

So now within the controller function, I handle the binding like this:

```
func RequestHandler() gin.HandlerFunc {
  return func(c *gin.Context) {
    var request ApplicationRequest
    if err := c.Bind(&request.Entities); err != nil {
        responseFunction(http.StatusBadRequest, ..., Message: err.Error()})
        return
    }
    // At this point, the request.Entities slice has ONE element, never more than one
  }
}
```

Note I'm using the gin context.Bind(...) function because it handles the parsing of JSON or XML implicitly, and works for all other scenarios that I need.

Hopefully this provides enough context, any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: it's not gin problem ->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27553274/unmarshal-xml-array-in-golang-only-getting-the-first-element

Comment: Just test your code with sample codes , https://go.dev/play/p/0yP1nkrr_8T, and test with `curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/xml"  -d '<Entities>    <Entity>        <Name>Name One here</Name>    </Entity>    <Entity>        <Name>Name Two here</Name>    </Entity> </Entities>' http://localhost:8080/`, the output is `{"entities":[{"Name":"Name One here"},{"Name":"Name Two here"}]}`, it work well to parse xml to slice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is not a gin problem:
[unmarshal-xml-array-in-golang-only-getting-the-first-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27553274/unmarshal-xml-array-in-golang-only-getting-the-first-element)

follow is two way to deal it:

- add a root node just like @zangw
- change the bind method by 'for'
  `github.com\gin-gonic\gin@v1.8.1\binding\xml.go` `line 28`  `func decodeXML`

from

```
func decodeXML(r io.Reader, obj any) error {
    decoder := xml.NewDecoder(r)
    if err := decoder.Decode(obj); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return validate(obj)
}
```

to

```
func decodeXML(r io.Reader, obj any) error {
    decoder := xml.NewDecoder(r)
    for  {
        if err := decoder.Decode(obj); err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF{
                break
            }
            return err
        }
    }
    return validate(obj)
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, the looping through objects to decode each fixed my issue, thanks so much!