# Array with different types or object inheritance

Tags: arrays, xml, go

I'm programming an xml response API in golang. Following the examples in the [xml documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#example_Encoder) it's pretty easy to create the xml giving them attributes and more.

The thing is that I need multiple tags under the same name and in different order.

```
<block>
    <tag1>A Value1</tag1>
    <tag2>B Value1</tag2>
    <tag1>A Value2</tag1>
</block>
```

By creating a structure like

```
type Tag1 struct {
    Value string `xml:",chardata"`
}
type Tag2 struct {
    Value string `xml:",chardata"`
}
type Block struct {
    XMLName   xml.Name `xml:"block"`
    Tags1     []Tag1   `xml:"tag1"`
    Tags2     []Tag2   `xml:"tag2"`
}
```

[I achieved](https://play.golang.org/p/6wNavkC37JV) this xml:

```
<block>
    <tag1>A Value1</tag1>
    <tag1>A Value2</tag1>
    <tag2>B Value1</tag2>
</block>
```

That's due to the array type inside the `block` definition. What I want, is a way to define that array type as an interface to inherit the two `Tag` types. Like this

```
type Block struct {
    XMLName   xml.Name `xml:"block"`
    Tags      []Tags   `xml:"tags"`
}
type (Tags t) Tag1 struct{
    Value string `xml:",chardata"`
}
type (Tags t) Tag2 struct{
    Value string `xml:",chardata"`
}
```

This way I could define the order of appearance in xml by the order of appending like

```
a1 := Tag1{"A Value1"}
b1 := Tag2{"B Value1"}
a2 := Tag1{"A Value2"}

arr :=  []Tags{}
arr = append(arr,a1)
arr = append(arr,b1)
arr = append(arr,a2)

v.Tags = arr
```

I've made some reading and I'm trying to avoid to implement the marshaling function used inside the xml package. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: There is no inheritance in Go. You could make `Tags` a slice of an interface type (either `interface{}` or something more specific) and do it that way. Types do not specify the interface(s) they want to implement.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/xTQWrYaA86m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it differently. I just wasn't looking for the right approach. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867417/golang-marshal-dynamic-xml-element-name#26867656) described what I needed. By defining the `XMLName xml.Name` value in the `Tag1` struct, I could define the name of the tag programmatically. And then just include the different Tags value with the old friend `[]interface{}` type.

```
type Tag1 struct {
    XMLName xml.Name
    Value   string `xml:",chardata"`
}
type Block struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"block"`
    Tags    []interface{}
}
a1 := Tag1{XMLName: xml.Name{Local: "tag1"}, Value: "A Value1"}
a2 := Tag1{XMLName: xml.Name{Local: "tag1"}, Value: "A Value2"}
b1 := Tag2{XMLName: xml.Name{Local: "tag2"}, Value: "B Value1"}

v := &Block{}
v.Tags = []interface{}{a1, b1, a2}
```

Check [this example](https://play.golang.org/p/pzTxTiJJ3BU) out to give it a play.